# Как составить sql запрос c объединением?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

в общем, есть проблемка, нужно объединить две таблицы в sql запросе.

1) Есть таблица с юзерами, основное поле - id

2) Есть другая таблица, в которой содержится user_id[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Нужно сделать так, что бы всё выходило в одной таблице (см. изображение), а вот как правильно составить SQL запрос, так и не понял. Может у Вас будут варианты?

Comment: `SELECT ... FROM users AS a LEFT JOIN another_table AS b ON (...)` RTFM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот этот запрос сработал, Вот полный код, может кому пригодится:

```html
<html>
 <head>
<meta charset="utf8">  
 </head>
 <body>
  
<?php
$host = 'localhost';  
$database = 'database';
$user = 'user'; 
$password = 'password';
 
// подключаемся к серверу
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database) 
    or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));
 
// выполняем операции с базой данных
$query ="SELECT users.first_name, users.last_name, value.value FROM users AS users JOIN value AS value ON users.id=value.user_id ORDER BY users.id ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link)); 
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
  
echo $row['first_name'] . ' ' . $row['last_name'] . ' ' . $row['value'] . '<br>';

 } 
// закрываем подключение
mysqli_close($link);
?>
 </body>
</html>
```